# Can ray-tracing be used to design a stealth air craft? Or is it necessary to use wave theory?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, diffraction

*This question is inspired/kicked-off by a question over in [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com) asking about the [design of stealth air craft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47676/why-does-the-f-117-nighthawk-look-different-than-other-stealth-planes/47677?noredirect=1#comment124511_47677).*

[Stealth technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_technology) is usually referred to when trying to make vehicles invisible to radar. While the first aircraft designs ([1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Have_Blue), [1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-117_Nighthawk)) featured mostly flat surfaces they already resulted in a [radar cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_cross-section) of [$0.001 \mathrm{m}^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-117_Nighthawk#Stealth).

[image: early stealth]

Later designs realise a radar cross section between [$0.001- 0.0001 \mathrm{m}^2$](http://www.ausairpower.net/APA-NOTAM-300309-1.html) with a considerable smoother aircraft shape.

[image: later stealth]

In order to design for stealth it is possible to calculate the radar cross-section. A superficial/quick internet-search points towards [Petr Ufimtsev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petr_Ufimtsev) and his works on edge diffraction in electromagnetics<sup>1</sup>.

While the initial answer cycled around limitations of CPU power being the cause for the polygonal design also the inability of Ufimtsev's equations to calculate [curved surfaces](https://books.google.de/books?id=qbZADCCtuvcC&lpg=PT46&ots=MpiQocUqbY&dq=Ufimtsev%20stealth%20for%20curved%20surfaces&pg=PT46#v=onepage&q=Ufimtsev%20stealth%20for%20curved%20surfaces&f=false) came where cited.

One of the comments argues that the simulations could use [ray tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(physics)) in order to predict the radar cross-section.

As stated above this comment inspired my question:
**Can ray-tracing be used to design a stealth air craft?**

---

[1] Ufimtsev, P.Ya. [Method of Edge Waves in the Physical Theory of Diffraction](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/733203.pdf), Soviet Radio, Moscow, 1962.

Comment: I wouldn't fly in it....is fluid dynamics not the usual method for design of aircraft, along with analysis of scattering of radar waves?

Comment: hm...the "design" should point towards the "stealth". The aerodynamic lift should definitely be predicted by some fluid dynamics. Do you have ideas how to alter the title-question?

Comment: Hmmm ... "radar" covers a lot of sins, I mean wavelengths. And scattering behavior depends in part on the relationship between size and wavelength. So the answer may be band dependent. Certainly, ray tracing for visual effects makes lots of approximations that assume the physical scale of objects is much larger than wavelengths.

Comment: Very helpful! That’s really a good way to structure the answer.

Comment: @rul30 you could maybe ask whether ray-tracing can be used to validate a stealth design, as opposed to designing the aircraft. - that would be the first step anyway.  At that point you would either design iteratively, manually or otherwise using the tool to rate the changes, or you could enhance it to lead further designs.  Either way, you would need to start with a model before you can use it for design.  Probably a better way to ask the question.

Comment: In optical simulations ray-based diffraction techniques have been proposed, see for example [Modeling physical optics phenomena by complex ray tracing](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/Optical-Engineering/volume-54/issue-03/035105/Modeling-physical-optics-phenomena-by-complex-ray-tracing/10.1117/1.OE.54.3.035105.full?SSO=1).